# Сообщает ли MongoDB о расположении Master

Tags: c#, mongodb

На сколько мне известно, запись ведется только через `Master`, а чтение возможно и из `Slave`. Однако встаёт такой вопрос: Если я подключился к `Slave` и знаю только его адрес (о других `Master` и `Slave` я ничего не знаю) и пытаюсь записать данные, то клиент `MongoDB` переключит меня на `Master`???

```
MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings();
settings.Credential = MongoCredential.CreateCredential("collection1", "user", "p@$$w0rd");
settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("192.168.1.100"); // Тут находится Slave
settings.ReplicaSetName = "myReplica"; //Реплика БД (Master<->Slave)
// Подключились
var client = new MongoClient(settings);
// Взяли Коллекцию
var db = client.GetDatabase("collection1");
//Найдем документ id=100
var filter = Builders<CacheDocument>.Filter.Gt<long>("id", 100);
//получим документ
CacheDocument document = collection.Find(filter).Limit(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Тут всё пройдет без запинки, однако, что произойдет, если мы будем писать данные

```
collection.InsertOne(new CacheDocument(/*something*/) { /*something*/ });
```

Переключит ли `MongoDB` на `Master` или выдаст ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечу на свой же вопрос:

Да! Если жив `Master` или жив `Arbiter` и есть кому назначать `Master`.

Любой из `Slave` в курсе где живёт `Master` и пересылает запросы добавления к нему.